# $.ajax not working in IE

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Do anyone know what is going on here? i wrote this code to call a php file to generate an image then display it out on the screen. Somehow this working fine for Mozilla and Chrome, but not in IE. Anyone know what is it going wrong for me code?

```
var src = $.ajax({
url: "em_captcha.php",
async: false
}).responseText;

$("#imgCaptcha").html(src);
```

Comment: what version of ie and jquery?

Comment: what is the AJAX call returning?  Only the src of the image or the complete `<img/>` tag?

Comment: @Steve: it will return the following code <img style='z-index:90' width='140' height='40' src='./image/captcha.png?".time()."' />

Comment: @Lester: IE8, jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2

Comment: I am not sure if this will help, but could you try: `$("#imgCaptcha").append(src);` instead?

Comment: @Steve, I think this is coz by the IE catching issue. Anyone know how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caching causing this issue, I have solved this issue by adding in the following code into the ajax:

cache: false,

Comment: Can you add that question binding dropdownlist using jquery in asp.net. I was just writing answer.(I know, this isn't right place to comment about it but i found only way to pass the message to you).

Answer (score 2):

what if you try:

```
$.ajax({
   url : "em_captcha.php",
   async : false,
   success : function(src){
      $("#imgCaptcha").html(src); 
    }
});
```

Comment: still the same, only working for mozilla and chrome, but not IE

Comment: @JinYong add an `alert(src);` before `$("#imgCaptcha").html(src);` what do you get ?

Comment: I put a trapping (echo "inside";) under em_captcha.ph, when I run in Mozilla and Chrome, word "inside" pop up from the alert, but not in IE

Comment: @JinYong when do you call $.ajax and what event fired it ?

Comment: I call the $.ajax when the link been clicked by the user. see my code here: $('#newcode').click(getImage);

Comment: @JinYong can i see the function `getImage()`

Comment: issue solve by added in the "cache: false" inside the $.ajax. Overall the IE catching actually causing this issue